# Bottom Strap Holder Broke, Can I Fix it?

Tags: electric-guitar, repair

So I was playing my Epiphone Les Paul Standard 100 and the bottom strap holder broke off.  Not the strap, but the thing built into the guitar that holds the strap.  I tried screwing it back in, but the past owner or I must have done something wrong because the screw won't screw back in.  I was wondering if you have any solutions or if I should just go to a guitar store and have them fix it.

Also, this is my first question on this site so tell please me if I did something wrong.

Comment: Broke off, or fell out? Pictures might help.

Comment: Sorry, fell out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If someone has previously drilled the hole larger, or swapped the screw, or even just continued to screw in a screw that was coming loose & eventually wearing the hole out… the task really just becomes "simple woodwork".

At its most basic, the hole needs to be smaller so the screw will bite.

You could use match sticks, cocktail sticks, chop sticks... wood filler, glue, a bigger screw…
literally anything that just makes the hole smaller than the thread.

Comment: Ok, and you don't think this could damage the guitar?

Comment: If you select wood that is too large and hammer it in, it could act as a wedge and split the wood. But if you are careful to size the replacement wood properly so it is snug, and use plenty of wood glue, you should be fine. Matchsticks and glue is good. a twig whittled down to the right size would work also.

Comment: Thanks, I used a toothpick.  Split it, stuck it in there, and then screwed it back in.

Comment: Great answer. Be careful with the bigger screw solution - it probably won't go through the hole in the little 'knob'. ( I had problems with Dunlop 'knobs'). A longer screw probably isn't a solution either.